# How to add a radio button with the help of buildQuickForm()

Tags: extension, forms

Showing data in the form of radio buttons.

> Data

```
$data[$count++] = array(dao->id,dao->names);
```

Above code return an array of id and names which is retrieved from database.
I want to put this data as radio button.
How to do that using buildQuickForm();

Answer (score 3):

Its pretty simple to add it as a group of radio button, adding below snippet on how you can add (not tested)

```
    $choice = [];
    forach ($data as $id => $value) {
      $choice[$value[0]] = $form->createElement('radio', NULL, '', $value[1], $value[0]);
    }
    $form->addGroup($choice, 'element_name_of_radio_button', ts('label of radio button'));
```

HTH

Pradeep